# Does the DNS response order matter in nslookup?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, nslookup

I've implemented a DNS relay program on Windows.
I got 3 DNS query every `nslookup` command, PTR, A and AAAA.
I reply the type=A query first, and reply PTR/AAAA query few microseconds later.
But I got timeout in `nslookup` and found that every A and AAAA response are received by localhost but PTR response got ICMP `Port unreachable` error.
I wonder why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requests for addresses (A and AAAA) are separate from the request for the PTR record.  Until you have an address your cannot request the PTR record.

For a typical SMTP reverse DNS validation lookup for IP `192.0.2.8` the process is as follows:

- Translate IP address into lookup format.
- Lookup PTR for `8.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa`.
- Receive PTR with name `smtp.example.org`
- Lookup addresses for `smtp.example.org`
- Receive address `192.0.2.8`

IP addresses are reversed for the lookup as it is necessary to lookup subnets such as `2.0.192.in-addr.arpa` to find the name server for the subnet.

Delegations of partial subnets are done using CNAME records.

Comment: Except _Windows_ nslookup first asks PTR _of the server address_ (unconditionally), then the query(s) specified by the user which defaults to A,AAAA (and no PTR) but can be overridden.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 PTR requests are meant to return the name matching the IP address. If you are querying for a name, then addresses would be requested first, then the PTR record.

Comment: A _program_ might do a forward lookup then reverse, but that is not what Windows nslookup does. Or BIND (Unix) nslookup either; _that_ does only the commanded query: if you ask for address it does address, not PTR or MX or SRV; if you ask for PTR it does PTR not address etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using UDP, TCP or both? When using UDP, are you using the same UDP port number that was the source of the original query as a destination port?
(In other words: when an UDP query comes in from IP address a.b.c.d port X to your IP address and port 53, the answer should be sent from your port 53 to a.b.c.d's port X.)

DNS can use both TCP and UDP: usually UDP is used first because it's fastest, but if the answer won't fit in a single UDP packet, the server puts in as much as it can and adds a flag that tells the client "here's the first part; if you need more, ask again over TCP to get the full answer".

Comment: Or the client use EDNS and asks for a larger buffer in UDP (signals that it can receive a bigger packet), see RFC6891.

Comment: I use UDP protocol. All three query(PTR, A, AAAA) is received from same IP addr and different port.  When I response type=A (IPv4 query) first and response type=PTR query later, I got ICMP error of the later response(PTR) that tolds me the port is unreachable.

Comment: Does the port of the PTR query closed when they received A or AAAA response?